# Confused about type hints in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, pycharm, type-hinting

Yesterday I upgraded from 2.7 to 3.6. I also started using type hints. Here
is a fragment of my code:

```
import numpy as np
from typing import Union, Tuple, Sequence, Any

Vector = Union[np.ndarray, Tuple[float, float, float]]
Matrix = np.ndarray
Tetra = Tuple[Vector, Vector, Vector, Vector]
...
def transform_ref2tetra(tetra: Tetra) -> Matrix:
    """ Return the matrix M that transforms the points of the reference tetra
    R=[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,0]] to tetra, i.e., M.R=tetra.
    """
    ...
```

When in PyCharm2016.3.2 I ask for Quick Documentation I get:

```
def transform_ref2tetra(tetra: Tetra)
Inferred type: (tetra: Tuple[Any, Any, Any, Any]) -> ndarray

Return the matrix M that transforms the points of the reference tetra
R=[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,0]] to tetra, i.e., M.R=tetra.
```

This is not just a documentation issue; if I call:

```
transform_ref2tetra(tetra=("a","b","c","d"))
```

I get no warning (and, of course, I get an error at runtime).

Any idea of what's going on? Is this a PyCharm problem or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with PyCharms' type-checker; `Tetra` as a type, is defined correctly by Python:

```
>>> Tetra
typing.Tuple[typing.Union[numpy.ndarray, typing.Tuple[float, float, float]], typing.Union[numpy.ndarray, typing.Tuple[float, float, float]], typing.Union[numpy.ndarray, typing.Tuple[float, float, float]], typing.Union[numpy.ndarray, typing.Tuple[float, float, float]]]
```

PyCharm, for some reason, seems to transform this to `Any`s which is wrong and leads to cases such as `tetra=("a","b","c","d")` being accepted as valid.

You should probably submit this to PyCharms issue tracker but my best guess is that `Any` is used since it cannot find any stub files for `numpy`.

Comment: That looked promising, but I don't think it's the case. Even of I change np.ndarray to int I get Any's

Comment: @Eduardo I really am not aware of how PyCharm's typechecker does things. `mypy`, another type checker, checks it correctly so I can only deduce that something is up with PyCharm.